# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PHPMailer\PHPMailer\mail() in /home/stitchon/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php:874

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am getting the above error upon submitting my registration form. I'm not quite sure what I'm overlooking. If I could get some direction and help on this, that would be wonderful. Thanks!

```
 858. private function mailPassthru($to, $subject, $body, $header, $params)
 859.     {
 860.    //Check overloading of mail function to avoid double-encoding       
 861.   if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 1) { // phpcs:ignore 
       PHPCompatibility.IniDirectives.RemovedIniDirectives.mbstring_func_overloadDeprecated
 862.     $subject = $this->secureHeader($subject);
 863.   } else {
 864.      $subject = $this->encodeHeader($this->secureHeader($subject));        
 865.     }   
 866.      //Calling mail() with null params breaks         
 867.       $this->edebug('Sending with mail()');     
 868.       $this->edebug('Sendmail path: ' . ini_get('sendmail_path'));  
 869.       $this->edebug("Envelope sender: {$this->Sender}");   
 870.       $this->edebug("To: {$to}");    
 871.       $this->edebug("Subject: {$subject}");    
 872.       $this->edebug("Headers: {$header}");    
 873.       if (!$this->UseSendmailOptions || null === $params) {    
 874.            $result = @mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);   
 875.        } else {    
 876.            $this->edebug("Additional params: {$params}");               
 877.            $result = @mail($to, $subject, $body, $header, $params);
 878.        }
 879.            $this->edebug('Result: ' . ($result ? 'true' : 'false'));
 880.           return $result; }

    /**
     * Output debugging info via a user-defined method.
     * Only generates output if debug output is enabled.
     *
     * @see PHPMailer::$Debugoutput
     * @see PHPMailer::$SMTPDebug
     *
     * @param string $str
     */
```

Comment: This is a wild guess, but I'm pretty sure the `mail()` function is a hard-wired built-in that can't be compiled as an optional module, which would seem to indicate that you're using a shared hosting provider who has configured PHP to completely forbid the use of that function in an attempt to avoid abuse from spammers. If this is the case, you'll be better off using an API-based email service like Mailgun or Amazon SES.

Comment: 1) drop the `@`, it's unnecessary. 2) add \ in front of mail, it's trying to namespace it when mail is actually a built-in function.

Comment: @AlexHowansky it's definitely a shared hosting and the provider has forbidden the use of the function I ended up using an API based solution and it's working currently thank you.

Comment: @aynber will sure try that and let you know thank you.